# plugin for plsql developer 9.0

Tags: plsql, formatting, plsqldeveloper

My job is to write plsql code in PLSQL Developer 9.0.6.1665. There are many formatting standards that I have to follow which cannot be accomplished using PL/SQL Beautifier Options.

Then I planned to write a plugin for my custom formatting. In the plugin I intend to grab the event when space or enter key is pressed so that when I type 'package' and the hit space it will be changed to PACKAGE. Likewise when I write 'insert into tablename' and then hit enter, the cursor position will be set below 'o' of into. But it seems that there is no event function provided by plsql developer to get the event of a key press. How can I solve this?

Any other suggestions for custom code formatting (other than provided by PL/SQL Beautifier) will also be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into Autohotkey -- it not only does what you want, but can prompt for parameters, etc. and you can also write complete programs with it if you want.  The nice thing about it is that it can be used in any program, not just PL/SQL Developer.

http://www.autohotkey.com/